# VBA ListBox problem when trying to find values

Tags: excel, vba, userform

When I try to search for "D 1" it works, but if I search "D 2" it does not work. What is wrong with this code:

```
Private Sub OptionButton2_Click()
    ListBox1.Clear
    For i = 2 To Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("BASE DE DADOS").Range("A:A"))
        If Worksheets("BASE DE DADOS").Cells(i, "B").Text = Me.ComboBox1.Text And Worksheets("BASE DE DADOS").Cells(i, "C").Text = Me.ComboBox2.Text Then
            Me.ListBox1.AddItem
                ListBox1.List(i - 2, 0) = Worksheets("BASE DE DADOS").Cells(i, "A").Text
            Me.ListBox1.AddItem
                ListBox1.List(i - 2, 1) = Worksheets("BASE DE DADOS").Cells(i, "AR").Text
            Me.ListBox1.AddItem
                ListBox1.List(i - 2, 2) = Worksheets("BASE DE DADOS").Cells(i, "AS").Text
            Me.ListBox1.AddItem
                ListBox1.List(i - 2, 3) = Worksheets("BASE DE DADOS").Cells(i, "AT").Text
            Me.ListBox1.AddItem
                ListBox1.List(i - 2, 4) = Worksheets("BASE DE DADOS").Cells(i, "AU").Text
            Me.ListBox1.AddItem
                ListBox1.List(i - 2, 5) = Worksheets("BASE DE DADOS").Cells(i, "AV").Text
            Me.ListBox1.AddItem
                ListBox1.List(i - 2, 6) = Worksheets("BASE DE DADOS").Cells(i, "AW").Text
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

DATA EXAMPLE:

[image]

Comment: Can you explain what this code is supposed to do? And what it currently does?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/esaRW4M using a data base it should show all the values for example D 1

Answer (score 0):

I refactored the code to make it easier for me to read. In doing so, I did not find a problem with the code. This makes me think that you have a problem with your data. I added `Trim()` on both elements where you are doing the comparison. This will eliminate the possibility that there are invisible characters in the data that cause the comparison to fail. Try this and let me know if it fixes the problem.

```
Private Sub OptionButton2_Click()
    Me.ListBox1.Clear
    Dim Dados As Worksheet
    Set Dados = Worksheets("BASE DE DADOS")
    For i = 2 To Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Dados.Range("A:A"))
        If (Trim(Dados.Cells(i, "B").Text) = Trim(Me.ComboBox1.Text)) _
        And (Trim(Dados.Cells(i, "C").Text) = Trim(Me.ComboBox2.Text)) Then
            With Me.ListBox1
                .AddItem Dados.Cells(i, "A").Text
                .List(i - 2, 1) = Dados.Cells(i, "AR").Text
                .List(i - 2, 2) = Dados.Cells(i, "AS").Text
                .List(i - 2, 3) = Dados.Cells(i, "AT").Text
                .List(i - 2, 4) = Dados.Cells(i, "AU").Text
                .List(i - 2, 5) = Dados.Cells(i, "AV").Text
                .List(i - 2, 6) = Dados.Cells(i, "AW").Text
            End With
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Now it show the values but gives the same error, look: https://imgur.com/a/SbFB906

Comment: Ok, that error is critical information that needs to go in the main question. This means you have gone outside the bounds of the listbox. How many columns does it have? Seven? How many rows does it have? The maximum number of rows is 65536 but you can run out of memory before that happens on 32bit Excel.

Comment: The excel has like 50 something. Maybe I need another cycle?

Comment: This can also happen if you are assigning a null value. Ensure all of those cells have data in them. Which line does the code stop on?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/thEUnjT This happens for D1, but for D2 it does not work for example

Comment: When appears another value different from D1 it stops and does not show any other D1

Comment: And what is the value of `i` and the text in column A for row `i` ? (I made a minor edit to the code.)

Comment: The value i is for me to start in row i, in this case i=2. Can I send you the excel file?